# Using bootstrap 5, how can I place my btn button vertically and horizontally in the middle over my two images in a responsive way?

Tags: html, css, responsive, bootstrap-5

How can I place my btn button vertically and horizontally in the middle **over** my two images? I'm trying to achieve this:

[image: this.]

Here is my button `<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link example</a>` and I'm using the latest version of bootstrap 5.

**MY CODE**

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link example</a>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid">
      <a class="btn btn-primary" href="#" role="button">Link example</a>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      //other code
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use the [flexbox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) (`display:flex`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check [Center elements](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/position/#center-elements), also, you need to move each image and button pair to its separate containers:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap-5 -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6 position-relative mb-5">
      <a class="btn btn-primary position-absolute position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" href="#" role="button">Link example</a>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6 position-relative">
      <a class="btn btn-primary position-absolute position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle" href="#" role="button">Link example</a>
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/1920x1080.jpg" class="rounded img-fluid">
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
      //other code
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```